# How to remove some rows in a group by in python

Tags: python, group-by, pandas-groupby

I'm having a dataframe and I'd like to do a `groupby()` based a column and then sort the values within each group based on a date column. Then, from a each I'd like to remove records whose value for `column_condition == 'B'` until I reach to a row whose `column_condition == 'A'`. For example, Assume the table below is one of the groups

```
ID, DATE, column_condition
--------------------------
1, jan 2017, B
1, Feb 2017, B
1, Mar 2017, B
1, Aug 2017, A
1, Sept 2017, B
```

So, I'd like to remove the first three rows and leave this group with only the last two rows. How can I do that?

Comment: What column are you using to groupby? `ID`? Could you show a more complete example of what you're doing?

Comment: Id is used for the group by and Date to sort each group

Comment: What function are you using to aggregate the groupby results? It's hard to understand where you're coming from.

Comment: there is no aggregation function. I just want to group by and then apply the logic I explained above on each group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I finally understand your question: you wish to `groupby` a `dataframe` by `'ID'`, sort by date, and keep the rows after the first ocurrence of `'A'` in your `condition` column. I've come up with the following one liner solution:

**Setting up dummy data**

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

d = {
    'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], # Assuming only two unique IDs for simplicity
    'DATE': [ # Dates already sorted, but it would work anyways
        dt.date(2018, 7, 19), dt.date(2018, 8, 18),
        dt.date(2018, 9, 17), dt.date(2018, 10, 17),
        dt.date(2018, 11, 16), dt.date(2018, 7, 19),
        dt.date(2018, 8, 18), dt.date(2018, 9, 17),
        dt.date(2018, 10, 17), dt.date(2018, 11, 16)
    ],
    'condition': ['B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B']
}
# 'DATE' but with list comprehension: 
# [dt.date.today() + dt.timedelta(days=30*x) for y in range(0, 2) for x in range(0, 5)]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

**Interpreter**

```
>>> (df.sort_values(by='DATE') # we should call pd.to_datetime() first if...
...     .groupby('ID') # 'DATE' is not datetime already
...     .apply(lambda x: x[(x['condition'].values == 'A').argmax():]))

      ID        DATE condition
ID
1  3   1  2018-10-17         A
   4   1  2018-11-16         B
2  8   2  2018-10-17         A
   9   2  2018-11-16         B
```

You can also call `reset_index(drop=True)`, if you need something like this:

```
   ID        DATE condition
0   1  2018-10-17         A
1   1  2018-11-16         B
2   2  2018-10-17         A
3   2  2018-11-16         B
```

`(x['condition'].values == 'A')` returns a `bool` `np.array`, and calling `argmax()` gives us then index where the first ocurrence of `True` happens (where `condition == 'A'` in this case). Using that index, we're subsetting each of the groups with a `slice`.

EDIT: Added filter for dealing with groups that only contain the undesired condition.

```
d = {
    'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], # Assuming only two unique IDs for simplicity
    'DATE': [ # Dates already sorted, but it would work anyways
        dt.date(2018, 7, 19), dt.date(2018, 8, 18),
        dt.date(2018, 9, 17), dt.date(2018, 10, 17),
        dt.date(2018, 11, 16), dt.date(2018, 7, 19),
        dt.date(2018, 8, 18), dt.date(2018, 9, 17),
        dt.date(2018, 10, 17), dt.date(2018, 11, 16)
    ], # ID 1 only contains 'B'
    'condition': ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

**Interpreter**

```
>>> df
   ID        DATE condition
0   1  2018-07-19         B
1   1  2018-08-18         B
2   1  2018-09-17         B
3   1  2018-10-17         B
4   1  2018-11-16         B
5   2  2018-07-19         B
6   2  2018-08-18         B
7   2  2018-09-17         B
8   2  2018-10-17         A
9   2  2018-11-16         B

>>> (df.sort_values(by='DATE')
...    .groupby('ID')
...    .filter(lambda x: (x['condition'] == 'A').any())
...    .groupby('ID')
...    .apply(lambda x: x[(x['condition'].values == 'A').argmax():]))

     ID        DATE condition
ID
2  8   2  2018-10-17         A
   9   2  2018-11-16         B
```

Comment: I'm trying it on my dataframe but for some reason it doesn't work!

Comment: no error but it doesn't work the way I wanted it. I also tried with argmin not nothing changes

Comment: Do you see any substantial difference between my dummy data and your real data? Is you `'DATE'` column in `datetime`?

Comment: I found the problem; if a group only contains 'B', it returns the entire group. How can we fix it/?

Comment: No, it does, from the [`np.argmax` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html#numpy.argmax): _Returns the indices of the maximum values along an axis.In case of multiple occurrences of the maximum values, the indices corresponding to the first occurrence are returned._

Comment: What's the expected result? If the group only contains 'B' it should be dropped all together?

Comment: so, if a group only contains 'B', I don't want that group

Comment: I've edited my answer to add a filter for conditions that do not contain any of the desired value.

Comment: Thanks, it works but may I know what the any() does and why it's argmax not argmin? cause we want to get the first A, so should't we use min?

Comment: Sure: `any()` returns `True` if at least one element is `True`, `False` otherwise. In our scenario, `any()` will return `True` it at least `x['condition'] == 'A'` evaluates  `True` at least once in each group. Thus groups without at least one `'A'` condition will return `False` and be filtered.

Comment: Regarding why `argmax` and not `argmin`: True can be represented by 1 and False can be represented by 0. In our case, an element will be True when it equals to `'A'`, thus, we're left with an array of 1s and 0s, and we're interested in the first maximum value (the first 1 or the first time an element equals to 'A'). Using `argmin` would return the position of the first 0, or the first time an element does not equal 'A'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a cleaner way to do this but I believe the following should work:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row["column_condition"] == "A":
        break
    elif row["column_condition"] == "B":
        df.drop(index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: so how to combine it with the group by?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with what you are trying to get out of a group by?

Comment: I'm doing a group by on my df and would like to apply this logic on each group. The example I showed above is just one of the groups

Comment: Can you post the logic for your group by? Without looking at it I would assume you can just iterate over the groups you have and apply this process for each.

Comment: I used your function in the apply() method after the group by
df.groupby('id).apply(lambda x: function(x)) but it looks like doing nothing!

Comment: I tried a similar operation on a toy example and it worked at removing the correct rows and stopping at a break condition.