# Delete records in each group based on condition pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame **submissions** with columns

```
['username','problem_name','result','submitted_on']
```

I want to group data frame based on `username` and `problem_name` and delete all submissions after result is equal to `accepted` (means first accepted result) of each problem of each user.

I have tried like this to group

```
df_username_groups=data.groupby(["username","problem_name"])
print (len((df_username_groups.groups)))
```

```
Example :
input:
username, problemname, result, sbmitted_on
xxx, abcd, wrong answer, 27/8/2018
xxx, abcd, wrong answer, 27/8/2018
xxx, abcd, Run time error, 28/8/2018
xxx, abcd, Accepted, 28/8/2018       
xxx, abcd, Wrong Answer, 29/8/2018   #Remove this problem already accepted
xxx, abcd, Accepted, 29/8/2018,      #Remove this problem already accepted
xxx, wxyz, Compile time error, 30/8/2018
xxx, wxyz, Accepted, 30/8/2018
xxx, mnop, Accepted, 31/8/2018
xxx, mnop, Accepted, 31/8/2018       #Remove this problem already accepted


output:
username, problemname, result, sbmitted_on
xxx, abcd, wrong answer, 27/8/2018
xxx, abcd, wrong answer, 27/8/2018
xxx, abcd, Run time error, 28/8/2018
xxx, abcd, Accepted, 28/8/2018
xxx, wxyz, Compile time error, 30/8/2018
xxx, wxyz, Accepted, 30/8/2018
xxx, mnop, Accepted, 31/8/2018
```

But do not know how to delete as per the above condition.

Comment: Provide a snippet of input and expected output as text in the question so that your need is clear and we can suggest appropriate solution.

Comment: provided samples. thanks in advance.

Comment: Finally found solution from [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51424613/how-to-remove-some-rows-in-a-group-by-in-python) for my requirement it has a simple change `data = (data.sort_values(by='time').groupby(["username","problemname"]).filter(lambda x: (x['result'] == 'Accepted').any()).groupby(["username","problemname"]).apply(lambda x: x[:(x['result'].values == 'Accepted').argmax()+1])) `

Answer (score 1):

Idea is compare column by `accepted` and then per groups use [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) for avoid remove row with first `accepted`:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
        'username':list('aaaaaa'),
         'problem_name':[4,4,4,5,5,5],
         'result':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'submitted_on':['q','accepted','new', 'accepted', 'w','ee']
})

print (data)
  username  problem_name  result submitted_on
0        a             4       7            q
1        a             4       8     accepted
2        a             4       9          new
3        a             5       4     accepted
4        a             5       2            w
5        a             5       3           ee
```

---

```
mask = (data.assign(new = data['submitted_on'].eq('accepted'))
            .groupby(["username","problem_name"])['new']
            .apply(lambda x: x.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum())
            .eq(0))

df = data[mask]
print (df)
  username  problem_name  result submitted_on
0        a             4       7            q
1        a             4       8     accepted
3        a             5       4     accepted
```